# Transfer ERC20 token from a smart-contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I am facing an issue and I can't figure what's going wrong.

It is a very simple scenario:

A smart-contract, that implements ERC20 and ERC20Mintable from OpenZeppelin.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "./openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Mintable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Mintable {}
```

Another smart-contract that received some MyToken.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./MyToken.sol";

contract TokenInteraction {

    address public tokenAddress;

    constructor(address _tokenAdd) public {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAdd;
    }

    function transferToken(address to) public {
        MyToken myToken = MyToken(tokenAddress);
        myToken.transfer(to, 1);
    }

}
```

I checked that TokenInteraction has more than one token, but when I call `transferToken` the transaction `revert`.

I don't understand what's happening.

Many thanks for you help!

**EDIT :**
Concerning the deployment and the testing methodology, I use Remix IDE on localhost and I deploy on Ganache running locally. To test it, I just mint a token to TokenInteraction and then try to call transferToken to another address

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I think worth mentioning. You're using MyToken when you only need IERC20. The contract looks okay from eyeballing it so i would focus on your deployment and testing methodology.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I agree with you that IERC20 contract could be used instead of MyToken but I originaly had more features in MyToken that I deleted to isolate my problem. 

Concerning the deployment and the testing methodology, I use Remix IDE on localhost and I deploy on Ganache running locally. To test it, I just mint a token to `TokenInteraction` and then try to call `transferToken` to another address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully transferred token with your code. I guess the reason why you encountered problem was a mis-setup at deployment. Please try out the following procedure with Remix IDE to see if it works for you.

#### Deployment

1. Deploy `MyToken` contract
2. Copy the address of the deployed contract
3. **Deploy `TokenInteraction` and pass the address copied at step 2 to the constructor.**
4. Once the `TokenInteraction` contract is deployed, check if `tokenAddress` matches the address got from step 2

#### Mint tokens to `TokenInteraction` contract

1. Copy the address of the deployed `TokenInteraction` contract.
2. Select a minter account (by default, the creator of the `MyToken` contract) and call the `mint` function with the address from the previous step as well as the amount.
3. Check with the `balanceOf` function to verify everything is good.

#### Transfer tokens to another address

Pass the recipient address when calling `transferToken` of `TokenInteraction` contract.

#### Verify Results

Check the balance of the recipient and that of the `TokenInteraction` contract.